# How to update RPM on an EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rpm

I'm trying to set up an application on an EC2 server, specifically an Amazon Linux 2 server. I'm trying to install MySQL, because the local version of the app uses it, and when I do I get an error saying the RPM version is incorrect. Specifically, it's `rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch`.

It's easy enough to find resources on how to update a package installed with RPM, but not so much changing the version of RPM itself. How do I do this? Is there a better way to solve this issue and get MySQL installed and running?

Comment: does this help? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: if not, please show what you are doing to try to install mysql and what is giving the error you mention

Comment: @ysth That did help, thank you! It helped me locate where the issue was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - the proper solution was using an older version of MySQL, not getting a newer version of RPM. I thought I might have made an error during installation.